# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css'

Tags: reactjs, react-sidebar

These are my import statements

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

//import react pro sidebar components
import {
    ProSidebar,
    Menu,
    MenuItem,
    SidebarHeader,
    SidebarFooter,
    SidebarContent,
} from "react-pro-sidebar";

//import icons from react icons
import { FaList, FaRegHeart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiHome, FiLogOut, FiArrowLeftCircle, FiArrowRightCircle } from "react-icons/fi";
import { RiPencilLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { BiCog } from "react-icons/bi";


//import sidebar css from react-pro-sidebar module and our custom css 
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import "./Header.css";


const Header = () => {

    //create initial menuCollapse state using useState hook
    const [menuCollapse, setMenuCollapse] = useState(false)

    //create a custom function that will change menucollapse state from false to true and true to false
    const menuIconClick = () => {
        //condition checking to change state from true to false and vice versa
        menuCollapse ? setMenuCollapse(false) : setMenuCollapse(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div id="header">
                {/* collapsed props to change menu size using menucollapse state */}
                <ProSidebar collapsed={menuCollapse}>
                    <SidebarHeader>
                        <div className="logotext">
                            {/* small and big change using menucollapse state */}
                            <p>{menuCollapse ? "Logo" : "Big Logo"}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="closemenu" onClick={menuIconClick}>
                            {/* changing menu collapse icon on click */}
                            {menuCollapse ? (
                                <FiArrowRightCircle />
                            ) : (
                                <FiArrowLeftCircle />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </SidebarHeader>
                    <SidebarContent>
                        <Menu iconShape="square">
                            <MenuItem active={true} icon={<FiHome />}>
                                Home
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem icon={<FaList />}>Category</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem icon={<FaRegHeart />}>Favourite</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem icon={<RiPencilLine />}>Author</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem icon={<BiCog />}>Settings</MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </SidebarContent>
                    <SidebarFooter>
                        <Menu iconShape="square">
                            <MenuItem icon={<FiLogOut />}>Logout</MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </SidebarFooter>
                </ProSidebar>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Referring this example from [this blog](https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-a-sidebar-menu-in-react-js-3463b306ca9a)

Error logs

`
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css' in 'D:\Rahul\Demo-ui\src\Components\Header'
ERROR in ./src/Components/Header/Header.jsx 17:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css' in 'D:\Rahul\Demo-ui\src\Components\Header'

ERROR in ./src/Components/Header/Header.jsx 34:37-47
export 'ProSidebar' (imported as 'ProSidebar') was not found in 'react-pro-sidebar' (possible exports: Menu, MenuContext, MenuItem, MenuItemFR, ProSidebarProvider, Sidebar, SubMenu, SubMenuFR, menuClasses, sidebarClasses, useProSidebar)

ERROR in ./src/Components/Header/Header.jsx 36:40-53
export 'SidebarHeader' (imported as 'SidebarHeader') was not found in 'react-pro-sidebar' (possible exports: Menu, MenuContext, MenuItem, MenuItemFR,
ProSidebarProvider, Sidebar, SubMenu, SubMenuFR, menuClasses, sidebarClasses, useProSidebar)

ERROR in ./src/Components/Header/Header.jsx 71:39-53
export 'SidebarContent' (imported as 'SidebarContent') was not found in 'react-pro-sidebar' (possible exports: Menu, MenuContext, MenuItem, MenuItemFR, ProSidebarProvider, Sidebar, SubMenu, SubMenuFR, menuClasses, sidebarClasses, useProSidebar)

ERROR in ./src/Components/Header/Header.jsx 140:39-52
export 'SidebarFooter' (imported as 'SidebarFooter') was not found in 'react-pro-sidebar' (possible exports: Menu, MenuContext, MenuItem, MenuItemFR,
ProSidebarProvider, Sidebar, SubMenu, SubMenuFR, menuClasses, sidebarClasses, useProSidebar)
`

Answer (score 3):

// import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";<- at the position you find the styles.css is not available because current version or pro-sidebar use differ file and that's name is also differ. So install that given

npm i react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1

Comment: Please try to be more specific and feel free to add the documentation link. It will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).